# How do i make my bot react to a message with attachments?

Tags: python, discord.py, nextcord

```
            channel = 1088438344024862810
            if message.channel.id == channel:
                await message.add_reaction("⬆️")
```

How do I make this only react when an embed is detected?

i didnt really try anything since i dont know how to make it detect attachments either

Comment: Hi, It seems you want to check if a message contains embeds or attachements. I recommand you to have a look to the documentation about [discord.Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message), what you are looking for is [here, about attachements](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments) and [here, about embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds). I recommand to add a condition like this `if message.embeds or message.attachments: await message.add_reaction('')`

Comment: it works, tysm!